# how to delete rows in a dynamically created datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dynamic, datagridview, vb.net-2010

i'm trying to delete rows in a `DataGridView` that will be dynamically created, i used this code but it's not working (dgv is not a member of...)

the datagridviews are created as follow:

```
If ComboBox1.Text = "Excel" Then
        Static Dim cmd As String
        Using fold As New OpenFileDialog
            fold.Filter = "sheet files (*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*"
            fold.Title = "Select file"
            If fold.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                fold.RestoreDirectory = True
                cmd = fold.FileName
            End If
        End Using
        Try
            Static Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim Dataset As System.Data.DataSet
            Static Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim shlist As ArrayList = getExcelSheetsName(cmd)
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & cmd & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
            For i As Long = 0 To shlist.Count() - 1
                Dim myTabPage As New TabPage()
                Dim dgv As DataGridView = New DataGridView()
                myTabPage.Text = shlist(i) & (TabControl1.TabPages.Count + 1)
                TabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage)
                myTabPage.Controls.Add(dgv)
                dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                dgv.AutoSizeColumnsModeDataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
                MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & shlist(i) & "$]", MyConnection)
                Dataset = New System.Data.DataSet
                MyCommand.Fill(Dataset)
                dgv.DataSource = Dataset.Tables(0)
                MyConnection.Close()
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try

    End If
```

and the code of the delete button is :

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In TabControl1.SelectedTab.datagridview.SelectedRows
        DataGridView.Rows.Remove(row)
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated... Thank You

Comment: What happens when the button is clicked?  Anything at all?  Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you can't use `TabControl1.SelectedTab.datagridview` because `datagridview` is not a member of `TabPage`, instead you can find the grid using `Controls` collection of a `TabPage` this way:

```
Dim grid = DirectCast(Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls(0), DataGridView)
If (grid IsNot Nothing) Then
    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In grid.SelectedRows
        If (Not dr.IsNewRow) Then
            grid.Rows.Remove(dr)
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: @AbdelouahedELHARIRI By the way, when you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the answer. It's not compulsory at all, but it's reasonable and recommended :)